# How to bring dragged div to top of everything while using two scrollers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroller

I have two horizontal scrollers and I need to drag div from upper scroller to lower scroller. This is working fine but the problem is that the dragged div gets lost under the scroller borders while dragged. Dragging comes from `jquery-UI` and scrollers smoothdivscroll.

Is there a way to fix it or should i start from scratch?

Here it is in http://jsfiddle.net/yCESP/

Here is list of jquery plugins.

```
jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
jquery.mousewheel.min.js
jquery.kinetic.min.js
jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js
jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js
```

Here is code

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="mainColumn">
        <div id="mixedContent2" >
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>1</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>2</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>3</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>4</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>5</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>6</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="koko_koira" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>7<br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mixedContent" >
            <div class="contentBox" style="background-color:#4254a3;color:white;">
                <br/>
                <p>FIRST</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="contentBox" style="background-color:white;color:black;">
                <p>SECOND</p>
            </div>
            <div class="contentBox" style="background-color:grey;color:white;">
                <p>THIRD</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    z-index:0;
}

#mainColumn {
    z-index:0;
}

#mixedContent {
    width:80%;
    height: 330px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#093;
}

#mixedContent .contentBox {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
    -moz-border-radius:5px; 
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #585858;
    z-index:0;
}

#mixedContent .contentBox img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#mixedContent .contentBox p {
    font-size: 10px;
}

#mixedContent2 {
    width:80%;
    height: 330px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
    border:2px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#06C;
}

.koko_koira {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 128px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0px 5px;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px; 
    -moz-border-radius:5px; 
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #585858;
    z-index:50;
}

.koko_koira img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mixedContent").smoothDivScroll({
        hotSpotScrolling: false,
        touchScrolling: true
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mixedContent2").smoothDivScroll({
        hotSpotScrolling: false,
        touchScrolling: true
    });
});

$( ".koko_koira" ).draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
});

$( ".contentBox" ).droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this)
            .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("p")
            .html("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should play with `overflow: hidden` and `overflow: visible` on `div.scrollWrapper` during drag/drop events. You also need to rethink the way you're positioning your top scrollers.

An updated fiddle (which sadly breaks up layout on drag event) can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yCESP/16/).

Drag events to listen to while dragging:

```
drag: function() {
    $('div.scrollWrapper').css('overflow', 'visible');
},
stop: function() {
    $('div.scrollWrapper').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped in the way that i wrapped everything inside another dv that is overflow: hidden, so now it looks as it works perfectly. :) Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCESP/17/).

Comment: I was too hasty. Scrolling works but when dragging something that is located normally outside border it jumps the row at beginning. So visible numbers can be dragged from number (i changed so it uses <p> tags as handlers so it is easy scrolling elsewhere upper row divs.) [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yCESP/18/).